# How to do orderless selection of each element from a set atleast once in regex?

Tags: regex

How to create a regex that matches characters which contain at least one of each of the `{"e","t","l","a","b"}`?

So for example if I run it on an English dictionary, it will produce words like

- aberrational
- blabbermouths
- table
- tablespoonful

Comment: chaining multiple lookahead assertion for each character works but it makes the regex too long is there a way to shorten the following regex? `(?=.*e)(?=.*t)(?=.*l)(?=.*a)(?=.*b).*`

Comment: There's no other way AFAIK (except if you project to write all permutations). But you don't have to worry about pattern length, you have to worry about pattern efficiency: for that replace each `.*` using an approptiate character class like `(?=[a-df-z]*e)...` and start your pattern with a word boundary.